# Error in Eclipse Java with AWS Toolkit updating Elastic Beanstalk environment - javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-toolkit

I'm using the latest Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200, with Java 12.0.1.

When I try to start a server to run my aws web project in Eclipse with AWS Toolkit, I get an error message:

[image]

Here is the Servers View:

[image]

Eventually the server stops, but the web project still says "Starting".

[image]

I'm really new to this. I have no idea what to do.

I don't see the application in the Elastic Beanstalk console. I'm just starting to learn how to set up CloudWatch with Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? Which version of Java is running it?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
Java 12.0.1

Comment: I used the latest versions of Eclipse and Java.

Comment: This "server" feature was working for me yesterday, but what I did was to create the project through the AWS toolkit and then the first time I ran it I did so from eclipse by selecting "run on server" and then created a new server manually from Eclipse. This "told" the eclipse aws toolkit to create the new beanstalk environment, which it did. Then it ran fine and I was able to update the server with changes I made in eclipse.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  JAXBException, no explanation.  Seems easier at this point to not use the AWS Toolkit